# Issue with TADODataSet on Delphi 10.1 Berlin. Query hangs

Tags: delphi, ado, tadodataset, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am trying to operate an `TADODataSet` in a program on **Delphi 10.1 Berlin**

Here is my code:

```
rsGrid.Connection := MyADOConn;
rsGrid.CommandType := cmdText;
rsGrid.CommandText := 'my_StoredProc 100';
rsGrid.IndexName := 'ObjectID';

rsGrid.Active := True; //***** Showstopper here! *****// 

while not rsGrid.Eof do
begin
   Memo1.Lines.Add(rsGrid.FieldByName('ObjectID').AsString);
   rsGrid.Next;
end;
```

The `Connection` property of the DataSet sets up as follows:

```
function TMainForm.MyADOConn: TADOConnection;
begin
    Result := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
    with Result do
    begin
        ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user15;Password=mypassword;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Data Source=my.server.com;Initial File Name="";Server SPN=""'';
        KeepConnection := True;
        IsolationLevel := ilCursorStability;
        Mode := cmUnknown;
        LoginPrompt := False;
        Connected := True;
    end;
end;
```

The database is SQL Server 2012, so I tried to run it with SQL Server Native Client 10 and 11 (`Provider=SQLNCLI10.1` and `Provider=SQLNCLI11.1` respectively).

I plan to use this TADODataSet later with a Grid component (via TDataSet) but I couldn't make this thing working In XE8, Seattle and now Berlin. It just hangs on `rsGrid.Active := True`. I also tried `rsGrid.Open` but it doesn't work as well.

At the same time it perfectly compiles and executes on my XE4.
What am I doing wrong in Berlin?

Comment: Pretty sure it's not related to your problem, but the way you're creating the connection object is screaming out memory leak. Every time you call that function `MyADOConn` it creates a new connection instance, and the only reference you keep to it is inside of `rsGrid`. I hope you're freeing it somewhere later, but even if so, the design is still majorly flawed and can still cause a big leak.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that Jerry, but here is just an example. In my real app the connection object is constructed and freed properly ;) Proven by MadExcept.

Comment: If you replace your TAdoDataSet with a TAdoQuery, can you successfully open it in the IDE using the Object Inspector?

Comment: @MartynA, In design-time I can perfectly open both TADODataSet and TADOQuery in Object Inspector. The only problem appears at run-time.

Comment: In that case, I think it's likely yo be something that only you can debug,but you should be able to easily find out exactly where it is hanging at run-time.  Make sure your project has "Use debug DCUs" checked under your project's Debug options, then trace into `rsGrid.Active := True`.

Comment: @MartynA thank you for helping on this. The problem was caused by **the missed attributes of ADODataSet component**. I've posted it as an answer, so it has a better clarification.

Comment: Glad you got it solved and posted as an answer, +1.  I think it's always better if you can solve these things yourself, makes it easier next time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happened. I am posting it as the answer, so it may help others who port the code from earlier versions of Delphi XE (prior to XE8) to XE8/Seattle/Berlin.

For some reason when you port the forms with TADODataSet component on it, it loses some key attribute(s). In other words, when transferred the component misses some attributes (i.e. `LockType := ltOptimistic`) which are important in my particular case.

**How To Make It Work**
To get your code back to life, simply *re-place* the `TADODataSet` component on your Form (delete it and place a new one).